# Is it possible to get all apache commons at once?

Tags: java, apache-commons

Sorry for such question since it is more my duty to search for it, but I looked everywhere and didn't find answer for it.

Is it possible to get all apache commons components in one jar or there is no such archive?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, we don't have a "all-of-commons" jar (nor should we). It'd be large, and the functionality would be a pretty bizarre mix. You could always (attempt) to create one yourself, but you might need to do some shading if there's any version mis-matching.

Comment: Pity, we have to manually go through a request system for every jar we download.  The inability to supply a single jar is going to create weeks of paperwork for us (or we'll have to go with a packaged commercial product I suppose)--Someone could make some cash packaging up apache jars for government consumption.

Comment: @BillK If you have essentially any Java open source project then you almost certainly already have almost all of them. Here's the thing: even if you had an über-jar you'd have the exact same amount of code auditing to do, not to mention the overhead of maintaining individual updates. It would be *far* more effort to do it that way. If you're implying you don't do the same level of auditing on commercial products I'm scared. If you do, you'd still need to do the same thing every time they updated, so same amount of work. ¯\(°_o)/¯

Comment: It's not a matter of auditing, it's a matter of compliance. For instance, we used Eclipse and had to request checks for Eclipse, subclipse, groovy-eclipse, .. (One for each plugin).  With IntelliJ we just needed to get clearance for IntelliJ, all the integrations are built in. It's not that commercial products are better, they tend to be packaged more completely. I'm not even going into the annoyance of not being able to use eclipse store or maven!  We must authorize and download each dependency separately. Also updating 1 jar weekly would be a LOT better than 10 jars that update occasionally!

Comment: @BillK That's still auditing, but whatever. The integrations are built in, but change.

Answer (score 3):

I highly doubt it.  It makes no sense to combine such a broad array of functionality into a single jar.  Most of the projects have nothing to do with one another and it is unlikely to require them all for a single application.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the whole of spring in one hit.  I have seen project "using" Spring, not as a container but as a way of including lots of libraries which can work together. i.e. no actual Spring class is used.

However I suggest you use a proper dependency management tool such as maven and you shouldn't need to download a jar yourself ever again. ;)

A good web site for finding dependencies is http://mvnrepository.com/ which have the XML you need to add to your pom.xml to get any version of most JAR you need.

Comment: That wouldn't be all of commons, though, I'm pretty sure. (I'm actually assuming the person making the OP look for such a jar doesn't actually want all of commons, too; that would be... uncommon.) I don't think *anything* uses all of commons.

Comment: I would think its possible to include all the commons, but I can't imagine a project using every one of them.

Comment: How can I download all of spring at once (Including Integrations and dependencies)?  I can't find any place to get this and it would be amazingly helpful considering that I cannot use any dependency management tool.